# How do I get a default route on a controller using WebApi & Attribute Routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I'm using WebApi and attribute routing.

I have a customer controller that has a method to get all the animals for that customer. This method & route work great. However, I also want a method that just returns a list of all the customers, and I can't get that one to work.

Here is my controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/customer")]
    public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet("{customerId}/animals")]
        public PagedHorse Get(int customerId)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Get");
        }

        [HttpGet("")]
        public PagedCustomer List()
        {
                Console.WriteLine("List");
        }
    }
```

If I change the List route to be `"{customerId}/List"` and ignore the parameter passed in, it works. What am I doing wrong with these routes?  I'd really like to just have `api/customer` return a list of all customers.

Comment: This is a straight forward scenario that should have worked. I tried it myself and wasn't able to repro the issue you mentioned. What is the response that you are seeing?

Comment: I'm getting a 404. But I'm using Hot Towel SPA, and realized it does some things with it's routing, so I'm going to check that out and see if there is some interference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there was some amount of interference between the Hot Towel SPA project type and my project. I didn't start from scratch with Hot Towel, but added it to an existing project, so I  believe there were some routing issues.

I deleted the HotTowel specific Configs (e.g. HotTowelRouteConfig) because everything that was done there I was already doing in my ASAX file.

After that everything worked fine.